# Select minimum value from a group in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to fetch like the winner bids, and a bid can be for a different date (don't ask why), so I need to select the bid with minimum bid price for each day.

Here are my models

```
Leilao
  has_many :bids

Bid
  belongs_to :leilao
  #winner_name
  #price
  #date
```

I tried a solution already and got close to what I need. The problem is that, in some cases, when I create a new bid with lower price, I don't know why the results do not change.

```
Leilao.find(1).bids.having('MIN("bids"."price")').group('date').all
```

This seems to work, but as I said, it does not work in some cases when I create a new bid. But it worked properly once. So, if you do know what might be happening, please tell me.

I then searched for some way for doing this and I got the following

```
Leilao.find(1).bids.minimum(:price, :group => :date)
```

which works properly, but with this, I just fetch the dates and prices and I need all the bid data.

I could get it by doing this, but it feels really bad to me

```
winner_bids = Leilao.find(1).bids.minimum(:price, :group => :date)
winners_data = []
winner_bids.each do |date, price|
  winners_data << Leilao.find(1).bids.where(price: price, date: date).first
end
winners_data
```

Any idea a better way to do this? Or what's wrong with my first approach?

Performance is not an issue, since this is just for academic propose but it just feels nasty for me

Also those Leilao.find(1) is just for explaining it here, I'm not using it allover the place, no.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this

```
mysql> select * from bids;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| id | winner_name | price | date       | leilao_id |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | A           |   1.1 | 2012-06-01 |         1 |
|  2 | A           |   2.2 | 2012-06-01 |         1 |
|  3 | A           |   3.3 | 2012-05-31 |         1 |
|  4 | A           |   4.4 | 2012-05-31 |         1 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bids where leilao_id = 1 group by date order by price asc;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| id | winner_name | price | date       | leilao_id |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | A           |   1.1 | 2012-06-01 |         1 |
|  3 | A           |   3.3 | 2012-05-31 |         1 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

in rails

```
1.9.2-p290 :013 > Leilao.find(1).bids.order(:price).group(:date).all
[
    [0] #<Bid:0x00000003553838> {
                 :id => 1,
        :winner_name => "A",
              :price => 1.1,
               :date => Fri, 01 Jun 2012,
          :leilao_id => 1
    },
    [1] #<Bid:0x00000003553518> {
                 :id => 3,
        :winner_name => "A",
              :price => 3.3,
               :date => Thu, 31 May 2012,
          :leilao_id => 1
    }
]
```

Comment: there some issue with mysql group by, it wont fetch the right records for grouped columns, and hence we need to first have sort as per need and then apply group by

Answer (score 1):

As Amol said its not going to work, the SQL looks like

```
SELECT "whatever".* FROM "whatever" GROUP BY date ORDER BY price
```

But the `group_by` will be applied before `order_by`

I had this trouble when i had market table where is stored different types of records, i solved it by writing a class method, maybe not the best approach but working

```
def self.zobraz_trh(user)
  markets = []
  area = self.group(:area).all.map &:area
  area.each do |market|
      markets <<  self.where(["area = ? and user_id != ?", market,user]).order(:price).first
  end
    markets
end
```

where self is Market class

Comment: Thanks! But I'm pretty sure a single query is better in this case.